# Change Azure AD Connect configured SQL Server name

Tags: windows, entra-id

We have our Azure AD Connect configured to use an external SQL Server for it's database. Is there a way to change the AAD Connect configuration to use another SQL Server name (hostname)?

The reason is that we migrated the AAD Connect database to another SQL Server.

I can't find anything on the documentation about changing an already configured AAD Connect, just about configuring new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to change de SQL Server name.

The following is what I did:

- Stopped the Azure AD Sync service (miiserver.exe).
- Changed two registry keys:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSOLCoExistence\CurrentVersion\SqlServerName
>
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ADSync\Parameters\Server

Both are string keys

- Started Azure AD Sync service.
- Done.

After that, I've tested and the syncronization worked with no problems.

Hope it helps anyone with this task, I didn't find any of the described procedure in documentations, so I don't know if it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be to uninstall and reinstall AADConnect I think. If you look at the FAQ [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-faq#environment), there's an extract that isn't aimed directly at what you're trying to do but does point the way indirectly:

> Q: Can I move the Azure AD Connect database from the local database to a remote SQL Server instance?
>   Yes, the following steps provide general guidance on how to do this. We are currently working on a more detailed document.
>
> Back up the LocalDB ADSync database. The simplest way to do this is to use SQL Server Management Studio installed on the same machine
>   as Azure AD Connect. Connect to (localdb).\ADSync, and then back up
>   the ADSync database.
>
> Restore the ADSync database to your remote SQL Server instance.
>
> Install Azure AD Connect against the existing remote SQL database. The article demonstrates how to migrate to using a local SQL database.
>   If you are migrating to using a remote SQL database, in step 5 of the
>   process you must also enter an existing service account that the
>   Windows Sync service will run as. This sync engine service account is
>   described here:
>
> Use an existing service account: By default, Azure AD Connect uses a virtual service account for the synchronization services to use. If
>   you use a remote SQL Server instance or use a proxy that requires
>   authentication, use a managed service account or a service account in
>   the domain, and know the password. In those cases, enter the account
>   to use. Make sure that users who are running the installation are
>   system administrators in SQL so that login credentials for the service
>   account can be created. For more information, see Azure AD Connect
>   accounts and permissions.
>
> With the latest build, provisioning the database can now be performed out of band by the SQL administrator and then installed by
>   the Azure AD Connect administrator with database owner rights. For
>   more information, see Install Azure AD Connect by using SQL delegated
>   administrator permissions.
>
> To keep things simple, we recommend that users who install Azure AD
>   Connect be system administrators in SQL. However, with recent builds
>   you can now use delegated SQL administrators, as described in Install
>   Azure AD Connect using SQL delegated administrator permissions.

Of course this rather depends on the uninstall working nicely and that a reinstall won't pick up previous settings and I'm afraid I haven't got a way of testing that for you.